# Calculate a couple of business days before a date

Tags: javascript, date

I have to calculate X working days before a date in javascript. I have an array of holidays, how can I do this?

I can make a while loop with my date and change it to the previous day and check if it's a business day then increment my variable but is it a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In normal languages you could easily solve this with a hashset. It has vary fast look up times, and random access.

However, Javascript isn't like all the other children. So it has it's own special way of doing this. The easiest way is just an object.

```
var holidays = {
1:true,
7:true,
18:true
}
```

I use days since newyear, but there isn't anything wrong with using a date or something else.

Then you can make a little helper function:

```
var checkDate = function(value){
  return holidays [value] === true;
};
```

Then you just do checkDate(dayOfYear) and it will return true or false if it's a holiday. Then you can easily do

```
//This is more pseudocode than javascript, since I haven't done javascript in years
while checkDate(--dayOfYear === true)
    previousBussinesDay = dayOfYear;
```

Or something similar to find the actual day.